# How to get the HttpHandler of an aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

How to get the HttpHandler of an aspx page?

For instance, I have **test.aspx** with code behind `public class Test : System.Web.UI.Page [...]`

If I call `new Test()` It doesn't return the exact same kind of HttpHandler that the one I get from `HttpApplication.Context.Handler` which can be access while browsing to **test.aspx**.

FYI (and definitivelly not the question): I need that because I'll be doing complex thing using `Server.Transfer(NewPageHandler)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a compiled instance of your page

```
System.Web.UI.PageParser
.GetCompiledPageInstance("~/YourPage.aspx",
                        HttpApplication.Server.MapPath("~/YourPage.aspx")
                      , HttpApplication.Context);
```

Comment: @Serge, could you please explain more. Not getting you clearly

Comment: Works great. I prefer your solution over Luaan's one, because yours doesn't require to know anything but the url (which make your solution more suitable for wide usage).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in your case `Test` is the parent of the actual `Test.aspx` class (ie. the ASPX file is compiled into a class that inherits from `Test`).

To get the `Test.aspx` instance, one option is to use the compiler directly:

```
BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/Test.aspx", typeof(Test));
```

Or you can use `PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance` as Murali Murugesan suggested, they're pretty much equivalent.

Note that this is not really supported ("This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."), but it does work mostly. I've actually switched to the default `PageHandlerFactory` in my code, which is a lot more stable:

```
class LuPageHandlerFactory : PageHandlerFactory
{
  public static LuPageHandlerFactory Instance = new LuPageHandlerFactory();
  private LuPageHandlerFactory() { }
}

// Which lets me call this:
var handler = 
  LuPageHandlerFactory.Instance.GetHandler
    (
      HttpContext.Current, null, "~/Test.aspx", null
    ) as Test;
```

A cleaner approach is simply to use `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/Test.aspx");` and pass the data in `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

My engine actually uses the last approach I mentioned as a fallback - if the `LuPageHandlerFactory` approach throws `SecurityException`, I fallback to `RewritePath`.
You should also handle `HttpCompileException`.